# What is the meaning of "negative loan balance" and "mobile money launderer"?

Tags: meaning

I find on google a lot but still don't know what is a "negative loan balance" and "mobile money launderer". Is it true that I can understand "mobile money launderer" as "money launderer"? Please give me some e.g about this two, thank you!

P.s I'm Vietnamese and I learn that from the Sicario movie:

> − See, you make payments over what you owe and it doesn't show up as cash, it shows up as a *negative loan balance*.

and:

> − What you got?
>   − Got a *mobile money launderer*.

Comment: Actually, a negative loan balance means that you have overpaid the full balance on your loan.  It does not mean that you are ahead of your payments. If you are merely ahead in your payments, but haven't paid the loan off completely, you still have a normal (i.e. positive) balance, which simply means you will owe less at the next payment (plus you might have eliminated some of the future interest).

Comment: I saw the edit history and I don't think those 3 sentences are related, especially between the first one and the second/third one. You need to include some more context before this question can be answered.